# How to override an elements style that is deeply nested by other classes/elements?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I am not able to override a CSS property on an element defined by class "ant-input-clear-icon". I have no access to it directly as it is imported from a library. However, I assumed I could wrap the nested elements in div and then use CSS specificity to select it/override. Can anyone help?

I am using LESS loader/CSS modules. Here is the markup (rendered by react):

```
<div class="ant_input_clear_icon_Wrapper8JxTE">
 <span class="ant-input-affix-wrapper ant-input-affix-wrapper-lg">
  <span class="ant-input-suffix">
    <i aria-label="icon: close-circle" role="button" tabindex="-1" class="anticon anticon-close-circle 
      ant-input-clear-icon"></i>
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS within a less module:

```
/*Make clear button larger */
.ant_input_clear_icon_Wrapper8JxTE {
  .ant-input-clear-icon {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
}
```

Note, that this works:

```
.ant_input_clear_icon_Wrapper {
  i {
    font-size: 19px !important;
  }
}
```

But seems like there should be a better way

Answer (score 1):

Try to put !important

```
.ant_input_clear_icon_Wrapper8JxTE {
  .ant-input-clear-icon {
    font-size: 19px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: No effect found

Comment: your code is perfectly alright.. https://codepen.io/Partha_Sarathy/pen/dyyKQqY

Comment: Even without !important also you code working good. i tested using LESS.

Comment: Yeah it should work, for some reason it doesn't.. Not sure why, oh well. I got around it with selecting the icon element, luckily. Thanks